# How to show the progress bar while downloading the database table data to Excel sheet in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, codeigniter

I am doing a task in which I wanted to download (or export to Excel sheet) the database table data to Excel sheet and while downloading the Excel sheet I wanted to show the progress of the downloaded file in the progress bar or show count of records worked on during the download.

Here is my code:

```
<?php require 'config.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post"  >
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
<span id="status"></span>
<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
<input type="submit" name="export_data" value="Export to Excel">
</form>

<?php
$output='';
if(isset($_POST['export_data']))
    {       
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        status.innerHTML = "Downloading Starts.....";

       </script>
        <?php
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users`");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            $output .= '<table class="table" bordered="1">                              
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>                                  
                            </tr>';
            $current=1;
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

                $percent= round(($current/$count)*100,2);
                echo "<script>bar.value = $percent;</script>";
                //echo "<p>$current is $percent% of $count";
                ?>


        <?php
                $output .= '<tr>
                                <td>'. $row["fname"].'</td> 
                                <td>'. $row["lname"].'</td>                                     
                            </tr>';
                            $current++;
            }       
            //exit();                               
            $output .='</table> ';
            header("Content-Type: application/xls");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");           
            echo $output;   
        }           
    }
?>

</body>
</html>

Any help is appreciated.
```

Comment: A progress bar in PHP is impossible as PHP outputs static HTML. You should be looking at a JavaScript solution using AJAX or something alike.

Comment: using javascript or jquery or bootstrap any scripting language...while downloading the excel sheet can we show how much percent data is downloaded?

Comment: The problem is that the server sends a response when it is finished fetching the results from the database. So your client (javascript) won't know how long it took until it is finished. The client really has no way of knowing how long it will take from the start, as the HTML and JS will be sent to it at the same time. You could use AJAX and then fetch the results one by one. That way you will be able to keep status if you know how many results you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion....if the records in the database is more than 200000 then AJAX will work or not?

Comment: Then fetching one by one would be a bit inefficient. But you could do it rough with say 20% a time. Then you should fetch `( 200000 / 5 = 40000 )` records a time. Or if that is too heavy, do a smaller percentage a time.

Comment: ok... i'll try sir